# Flutter: StreamBuilder with Firebase

Tags: flutter, listview, firebase-realtime-database, stream-builder

I have a `ListView` of objects from `Firebase` in which I would like to have it refresh using a `StreamBuilder` when the data changes.

I can load up my list fine & when data changes my list does refresh.

The issue I am having is instead of the `ListTile` that has the change just updating, I see that tile being duplicated so I see the new change & the old change.

Here's my setup:

```
final ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
late DatabaseReference itemRef;
late FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase();
late StreamSubscription _objectInfoStreamSub; // Not sure if needed?
late List<CustomObject> data = [];

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    final keys = Global.kData.keys;

    for (final key in keys) {
      // Initialize this...
      itemRef = database.reference().child('ABC').child(key.toString());
    }

    // Load the data...
    _setListeners();
}

// Here is where I load my data initially...
Future<void> _setListeners() async {
    // Clear out our data before we reload...
    data.clear();

    final keys = Global.kData.keys;

    for (final key in keys) {
      _objectInfoStreamSub =
          ref.child("ABC").child(key.toString()).onValue.listen(
        (event) {
          setState(() {
            // Mapped the data...
            final firebaseData = Map<String, dynamic>.from(event.snapshot.value);

            // Create the Room...
            final room = CustomObject.fromJson(firebaseData);

            // Check if blocked...
            // Logic to see if user is blocked
            
            // check if isArchived
            // Logic to see if room is archvied

            if (!isBlocked && !isArchived) {
              if (!data.contains(room)) {
                data.add(room);
              }
            }

            // Sort by date
            // Logic to sort so the most recent is at top
          });
        },
      );
    }
}

// Here is my updated StreamBuilder...
SliverToBoxAdapter(
  child: StreamBuilder<dynamic>(
    stream: itemRef.child('ABC').onValue,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      }
      if (snapshot.hasData &&
                        snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
        return ListView.builder(
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: data.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return ChatRoom(
              data: data[index],
            );
          },
        );
      } else {
        return Container();
      }
    },
  ),
),
```

Comment: If you're using `List data` to be displayed on CustomListTile, then shouldn't you be depending on the snapshot from the StreamBuilder? It's unclear on how `List data` is being updated from the code snippet you've provided.

Comment: You are sure, you do not have duplicated data on Firebase, right?

Comment: Correct. I have a refresh button and if I tap that then it resets my ListView back to normal. Within the method that is called I am clearing out the data & obtaining it again. So, something within my streambuilder isn't doing the same thing. It's just seeing there's something new and adding it vs. finding the right row & just updating that row.

Comment: I've updated my code above.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this causes your problem, but try wrapping the `ListView.builder()` with `StreamBuilder` instead of only it's items. Because in your current state of code, if you would add another item and your `data.length` would change, the `ListView.builder()` wouldn't get rebuilt and it wouldn't build new data.

Comment: My question with this is, do I need to be doing this -> .child(data[index].toString()) If so, how would I get the index for the item then? I had tried the reversed way prior but was also seeing the same results.

Comment: prior I had just tired itemRef.onValue as the stream

Comment: I think you need `itemRef.child('ABC').onValue` to use it as a stream, if that doesn't work please provide code how is your `data` and `itemRef` initialized

Comment: I've updated my code above.

Comment: Is the output the same as before, when you use `itemRef.child('ABC').onValue` as a stream? Does it work fine?

Comment: Getting the same results. I open the app in my simulator, tap on the tab that shows my list of chat rooms, data loads fine. Then I open the app on my iPhone, go into one of the chat rooms & send a new message. On my simulator, I see the update but now I see a duplicate row of the room I updated. I see a new row added above the other so I see both the previous data & the new data just added.

Comment: I can't see code where you update your `List<CustomObject> data`, so maybe you are adding the room to the list, when you should replace the existing one?

Comment: + Just as side note, when you will be working on another project try to give your variables clearer names, because current ones are really confusing.

Comment: Correct, I need to replace the existing one but I don't know how

Comment: Can you provide code where you update `List<CustomObject> data`?

Comment: It's all above. The setListners code loads everything initially and then if I make a change within a chat room the stream builder is picking it up and making changes. just not the changes I want. and I have a refresh button that just calls setListeners.

Comment: data.add(room); --> this is what is triggered when I add a new message within my chat room. So it is adding it as a new room but I need to see if it exists & just update it vs. add it as new.